# Dynamically set Python interpreter optimization at runtime

Tags: python, compiler-optimization, assert, interpreter, cpython

After a while of looking for the duplicates in here the only thing I find is no-ops and optimizing with Cython which is completely unrelated. What I'm trying to accomplish is to **dynamically set `python -O` flag at runtime**.

Basically, there is one value `sys.flags.optimize` which is read-only. I'm looking for an option to change it or to find a place which can have this value changed and affects the bytecode generating.

According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files) the official way is to call it before the interpreter is spin up, so I wonder if it's even possible, however this is what I've found:

- [`Python/compiler.c -> c_optimize`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/99b54d68172ad64ba3d0fdc0137f0df88c28ea2b/Python/compile.c#L161)
- [`optimization_level`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8462a4936b3a551dc546a6adea04a70b0a07ca67/Python/initconfig.c#L1251) setup in C from environment variable `PYTHONOPTIMIZE`
- [`Lib/py_compile.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e33ecd7c9b0cac3efc6fcbdd4547fd086b4e2d1/Lib/py_compile.py#L79)

Which seems like `py_compile` is called "somewhere" (GitHub search shows only doc or tests, not the actual caller at runtime) and manages the `optimization_level` in the `compiler.c` from above. That would mean I can change it within Python and make compiled interpreter assemble me code with and without optimizations in the same session/process.

I can't seem to find the CLI params parsing though, nor any related "state" that can be changed at runtime.

My target (for now) is to optionally allow/remove `assert` keyword which can be done by `-O` alone (via [`compiler_assert()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/99b54d68172ad64ba3d0fdc0137f0df88c28ea2b/Python/compile.c#L3256) that needs the level set, however I'm struggling with finding the "missing link" between C code building AST and the actual Python code which seems to be holding the config state (because `py_compile` contains raw `optimize` values) and seems to be compiling and loading the bytecode for the interpreter itself.

Is there any way to change the `optimization_level` so that I can achieve this behavior and pretty much do this in a single Python session?

```py
>>> # change optimize to 1
>>> def test(): assert True
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> # change optimize to 0
>>> dis.dis(test)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         8
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (AssertionError)
              6 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Your interpreter starts with some level of optimization and compiles all .py files to .pyc, then they are processed by interpreter. If you change optimization level in runtime it won't have any effect - .pyc files are already compiled.